# Multithreading a filestream in vb2005

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to build a resource file for a website basically jamming all the images into a compressed file that is then unpacked on the output buffers to the client.

my question is in vb2005 can a filestream be multi threaded if you know the size of the converted file, ala like a bit torrent and work on pieces of the filestream ( the individual files in this case) and add them to the resource filestream when they are done instead of one at a time?

Comment: Putting all images into a compressed file? Aren't your images already compressed in some form (JPG, GIF, PNG, ...)?

Comment: They are, i was wondering if i put them in a zipfile if i could save some space, so i was making my own fileformat and compressing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're asking if a System.IO.FileStream object can be read from or written to in a multi-threaded fashion.  But the answer in both cases is no.  This is not a supported scenario.  You will need to add some form of locking to ensure serialized access to the resource.

The documentation calls out multi-threaded access to the object as an unsupported scenario

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you need something similar to the torrents way of writing to a file, this is how I would implement it:

1. Open a FileStream on Thread T1, and create a queue "monitor" for step 2
2. Create a queue that will be read from T1, but written by multiple network reader threads. (the queue data structure would look like this: (position where to write, size of data buffer, data buffer).
3. Fire up the threads

:)

Anyway, from your comments, your problem seems to be another one..

I have found something in, but I'm not sure if it works:

> If you want to write data to a file,
>   two parallel methods are available,
>   `WriteByte()` and `Write()`. `WriteByte()`
>   writes a single byte to the stream:

```
byte NextByte = 100;
fs.WriteByte(NextByte);
```

> `Write()`, on the other hand, writes out
>   an array of bytes. For instance, if
>   you initialized the `ByteArray`
>   mentioned before with some values, you
>   could use the following code to write
>   out the first nBytes of the array:

```
fs.Write(ByteArray, 0, nBytes);
```

Citation from:

> Nagel, Christian,  Bill Evjen,  Jay
>   Glynn,  Morgan Skinner, and Karli
>   Watson. "Chapter 24 - Manipulating
>   Files and the Registry". Professional
>   C# 2005 with .NET 3.0. Wrox Press.  ©
>   2007. Books24x7. http://common.books24x7.com/book/id_20568/book.asp
>   (accessed July 22, 2009)

Comment: ya, i was hoping the io stream could be written to by multiple threads given i know the pointer and the files's size, doesnt work that way it seems

Comment: It seems that there could be a solution using a FileStream. I'm checking it right now and let you know

Comment: you use buffers to write to the stream, the problem is like acessing a control that has been created on a diffrent thread, and im only writing to part of that thread, ill try a few things and then we shall see, im thinking of loading the files into memory then using the buffer to write to a defined area